# Windows 10 Password Error with Samba Share

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, encryption, samba

I am trying to connect to a samba share with Windows 10 Pro (Version 1511, Build 10586.589) using the command `net use L: \\myserver\myshare /u:myuser mypassword`. I get the error:

```
System error 86 - The specified network password is not correct.
```

I get the same result when using the Map network drive dialog.
Other clients (Android, Linux) can connect just fine with the same user/password.

I have tried adjusting the following security policies via secpol.msc:

- Microsoft network client: Send unencrypted password to third-party
  SMB servers (enabled and disabled)
- Netword security: LAN Manager authentication level (Send LM & NTLM responses, Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated
- Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based
  clients/servers (128-bit encryption and none)

I am running samba 4.5.0-2 on Arch Linux (4.7.4-1). Server-side, I have reset the user password, removed and re-added the user to the smbpasswd backend, and started and restarted the smbservice.

My smbconf is basically the default:

```
 [global]
   workgroup = MYGROUP
   server string = Samba Server
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   max log size = 50
   security = user
   encrypt passwords = yes
   smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
   unix password sync = Yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *New*UNIX*password* %n\n *ReType*new*UNIX*password* %n\n *passwd:*all*authentication*tokens*updated*successfully*
   dns proxy = no
[my share]
   comment = my share
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = no
   path = /pathto/myshare
   public = no
   valid users = myuser
   create mask = 770
```

I don't see anything out of the ordinary in testparm, and I have confirmed via pdbedit that my user is definitely registered with the backend.

It has worked fine before today and I do not know why it suddenly stopped working. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

if anyone else runs into this problem, my solution was to adjust the security policies on the Windows client.

Run > Secpol.msc

then I set Local Policies > Security Options > Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level to 'Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM & NTLM'

and the client connects just like before.

Comment: This solved it for me, but I didn't feel happy with it, as it requires a change on all my machines. Instead adding the line `ntlm auth = yes` to my `smb.conf` did the trick as well.

Comment: I've had this option set to that exact value while it didn't work. @Niels's answer got it right and now it works.

Comment: The thing is, according to Microsoft `Send NTLMv2 response only. ` should be the default in Windows 10. For some reason it wasn't. I suspect that enabling SMBv1 support in Windows features changes that parameter so they can work.

Answer (score 50):

You can also fix this on the server (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) side:
In `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, put:

```
ntlm auth = true
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: should this be placed under [global] or samba-share?

Comment: @waqaslam under [global]

Comment: I can confirm this works.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Could someone please explain what this actually does, though?

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this answer... I've lost at least a couple of days trying to find the solution for this problem... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I just fixed a desk pounding auth issue when trying to access a FreeBSD samba share from Windows 7 Ultimate. I followed this tutorial: https://www.davd.io/samba-fileserver-on-freebsd/ and it just wouldn't work. Adding this line to [global] instantly fixed my issue after restarting samba. This should be the accepted fix as it corrects the auth problem at the server, not force the user to change the security policy of *EACH* individual Windows machine. Madness.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, worked for me!
What does it actually does tho?

Comment: You're an angel. I was stuck on this for 2 days and this little line fixed it in an instant.

Comment: I did an upgrade to 20.04 LTS and samba version was upgraded with conf file. Whats surprising is samba access worked for a win 10 machine without this setting. After setting this param, it started working on the another machine where I was blocked

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is correct, and works for Windows 10 Professional and above. However, Windows 10 Home lacks `secpol.msc` and its easy-to-use interface.

To fix this on Windows 10 Home, navigate to the following key in the registry:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
```

Look for a DWORD value named `LmCompatibilityLevel`. If it does not exist, create it. Set the value to `5`.

After making this change, I was immediately able to access the Samba server without restarting.

<sup><sub>Source: [Changing LAN Manager Authentication on Windows NT](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/255/)</sub></sup>

Comment: @user76225  This really helped me. Though I was using Win 10 Pro, the option in secpol.msc is disabled as it is joined to different domain with tight policies

Answer (score 9):

And when you get tired of fighting with Windows and Samba, go here:

https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win

It's file sharing over SSH. No need for Samba or trying to get Windows to play nice.

Comment: For some people, this solution is good enough!  Why downvote it just for semantic reasons?

Comment: Because it's not related to the question? If someone wants an alternative then they can Google 'Samba windows alternative or something similar.

Comment: I would like to add, if you do choose to go with mcmacerson's file sharing over ssh solution **(which is the only solution that worked for me after 2 hours of trying everything else)**, you'll also need to enable ssh on ubuntu (it's not enabled by default). Here's how to do it: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a new issue when trying to log into a Samba Share while also using Microsoft Account to log into Window. The issue behaves the same "Incorrect Password" and therefore I confused it with this issue for hours.

The solution is to use the Microsoft Account Credentials when trying to log into the Samba share (I know, this still does not make sense to me but it worked). Type:
User:MicrosoftAccount\me@email.com
PW:

This is documented here [How to login to network share when Microsoft Account is tied to windows login?](https://superuser.com/questions/740375/how-to-login-to-network-share-when-microsoft-account-is-tied-to-windows-login)