# Share Windows 10 PC folder to User on Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, home-networking, file-sharing

Let's say I have a folder, "c:\my_stuff" on my Windows 10 PC.
The Windows 10 PC is named "win10PC".

I have a laptop, "win7lap", running Windows 7 with multiple users.

They are connected on the same network.

I would like to share the "c:\my_stuff" to user "Thomas" on the laptop.

The solutions for Windows 10 suggest using a Homegroup, but Homegroups were removed from Windows 10.  I don't see anything about creating a homegroup when I follow the instructions for Windows 10.

Windows 10 will let me share a folder with specific users on the Windows 10 PC or with "everyone".  I don't want to share the folder with everyone on the network, only with an account on the Windows 7 laptop.

How do I share a Windows 10 PC folder with a User on a Windows 7 laptop on the same network?

*FYI, this is a home network with a Windows 10 PC, a Windows 7 laptop, cell phones and tablets.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share the folder `c:\my_stuff` as **MyStuff** and set full permissions to the current user on Windows 10.

On the Win7 Laptop, login to the Thomas account, [map a network drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive) (as netowrk folder typein **\win10PC\MyStuff** and select the **Reconnect at logon** check box.

[image]

Type in the [account data from Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/740708/174557) and store them on your Windows 7 laptop to avoid reentering the password again.

Comment: This solution is only desirable if you're OK with handing your Win10 login info to your Win7 computer. Let's say the Win10 computer was mine and the Win7 computer belonged to my roommate.  I want him to have access to MyStuff and only MyStuff.  Then what would I do?

Comment: @JoeC create a dummy account (datatransfer) and the win7 user has to enter this username