# Can't access windows 10 shared folders with account/password

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, shared-folders

I'm trying to access the folders I shared on Windows 10 through my Android phone. Using Samsung's "My files" I am able to add the SMB network drive.

When I turn OFF password protected sharing and sign in anonymously, everything's fine. I can access the files/folders I share. But when I turn it ON and access with my windows account email and password, it doesn't let me in. Seems like either the account's Username or Password are incorrect.

I have only one profile on my windows, registered with my email. I changed the password to be sure I wasn't remembering it incorrectly. Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using some other password?

Comment: Please test this
https://superuser.com/a/740708/1108395

Comment: May I know how did you set the share permissions on windows 10 shared folder?

Comment: @Sunny through simply right clicking on the files/folders and "give access to". With password protected sharing OFF, I added permissions to "Everyone", with pps ON I only added my account.