# Unable to connect to a shared disk on Windows using a Microsoft account

Tags: windows, samba, smb

I installed Windows from scratch on a new PC and logged in using a Microsoft account. I shared a disk but was unable to open it from another computer in my network using the same Microsoft account. I tried all the recommendations from the popular question [How to login to network share when Microsoft Account is tied to windows login?](https://superuser.com/questions/740375/how-to-login-to-network-share-when-microsoft-account-is-tied-to-windows-login) but none of them helped.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause turned out to be simple: I had logged in without a password using an Authenticator app, so Windows didn't have my password on record.

To resolve this, I locked the screen, clicked the 'I forgot my PIN' link, and logged in using my password. Changing the PIN or turning it off wasn't necessary. The purpose of this trick is solely to provide the OS with your actual password.

Once it's done you can log in from a remote machine using your email and password, and open the disk. No prefixes like "MicrosoftAccount" are needed.